# Property instantiation

Tags: properties

I am trying to understand what instantiation means, at the moment I believe it is the act of assigning a property to an object, is this correct?

If so, can a property be instantiated by another property?

Comment: There are so-called first-level properties that are predicated of objects (particulars); thus, the property "being a Philosopher" is predicated of (instantiated by) Socrates.

Comment: There are second-level properties that are predicated of first-level properties. According to Frege (and Kant), existence is a second-level property: the property of a property of "being Instantiated".

Answer (score 1):

The word "instantiate" is related to "instance". If someone says, "Name some things that are red." you could answer, "For instance, roses are red, apples are red, blood is red." In other words, roses, apples and blood are instances of the property red. In other words, roses, apples, and blood instantiate the property red.

That's all "instantiate" means. An object x instantiates a property p if p(x). That is, x instantiates p if x has the property p, if x exhibits p, if x is an instance of p. All are ways of saying the same thing (with possibly some subtle metaphysical distinctions).

So, yes a property can be instantiated by another property. The property "is a color property" is instantiated by the property red.

Answer (score 1):

If an apple p and a paint swatch s both have the property red. We can say that they are instances of the set Red Things. However, as such they are object instances not property instances. The idea of a property instance is that in addition to p and s you have the redness of the apple, r(p), and the redness of the swatch r(s). These are not in the set Red Things, however, they are instances of the property Redness. To speak this way presupposes an ontology in which not only objects, but also properties of those objects may be quantified over and thus formed into sets. It is natural to think this way in higher-order logic but not so much in standard first order logic.

See Graham Priest's book One (2014), where he describes property instances and gives them the pithy name PINs.